# Automatically update method signature (for ex. summary comments)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I'm looking for a way to automatically match the signature of a method between an interface, an abstract class and a derived class. It's really painful when I change one of the comments, to manually update it 3 times, because I have to update it in the interface, the abstract class and the derived class.. Is there a VS extension or something that could help me do that automatically? Btw, I'm using ReSharper Ultimate. Not sure if it has a such extension.

```cs
public interface IBotClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets account balance for an asset.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="asset">The asset.</param>
    /// <param name="ct">Cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>The account balance.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:ElonMuskBot.Core.Exceptions.CallFailedException">If the call fails.</exception>
    Task<Balance> GetBalanceAsync(string asset, CancellationToken ct = default);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets account balances.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ct">Cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>The account balances.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:ElonMuskBot.Core.Exceptions.CallFailedException">If the call fails.</exception>
    Task<IList<Balance>> GetBalancesAsync(CancellationToken ct = default);

    ...
}

public abstract class BotClientBase : IBotClient
{
    private readonly IBinanceClient _client;
    private readonly IBinanceSocketClient _socketClient;

    protected BotClientBase(IBinanceClient client, IBinanceSocketClient socketClient)
    {
        _client = client;
        _socketClient = socketClient;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets account balance for an asset.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="asset">The asset.</param>
    /// <param name="ct">Cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>The account balance.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:ElonMuskBot.Core.Exceptions.CallFailedException">If the call fails.</exception>
    public abstract Task<Balance> GetBalanceAsync(string asset, CancellationToken ct = default);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets account balances.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ct">Cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>The account balances.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:ElonMuskBot.Core.Exceptions.CallFailedException">If the call fails.</exception>
    public abstract Task<IList<Balance>> GetBalancesAsync(CancellationToken ct = default);

    ...
}

public class SpotBotClient : BotClientBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<SpotBotClient> _logger;
    private readonly IBinanceClient _client;
    private readonly IBinanceSocketClient _socketClient;

    public SpotBotClient(ILogger<SpotBotClient> logger, IBinanceClient client, IBinanceSocketClient socketClient) : base(client, socketClient)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _client = client;
        _socketClient = socketClient;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets account balance for an asset.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="asset">The asset.</param>
    /// <param name="ct">Cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>The account balance.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:ElonMuskBot.Core.Exceptions.CallFailedException">If the call fails.</exception>
    public override async Task<Balance> GetBalanceAsync(string asset, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets account balances.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ct">Cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>The account balances.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:ElonMuskBot.Core.Exceptions.CallFailedException">If the call fails.</exception>
    public override async Task<IList<Balance>> GetBalancesAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the comment in the interface be enough?

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps you can use [<inheritdoc>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/inheritdoc)? (I haven't tried it though)

Comment: @Xerillio, thank you! I will try that one

Comment: @Xerillio, hmm, what's more correct. To type all comments in the interface and the abstract class and the derived classes to inherit them?

Comment: Think about the "inheritance hierarchy". The interface does not depend on any of the others, while the other two depend on the interface, so I'd say the interface makes most sense.

Comment: @Xerillio, thank you! Type that as an answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation comments in C# allows you to use the [`<inheritdoc>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/inheritdoc) tag, to automatically let derived types reuse the documentation comments from higher up in the hierarchy:

```
public interface IBotClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets account balance for an asset.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="asset">The asset.</param>
    /// <param name="ct">Cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>The account balance.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:ElonMuskBot.Core.Exceptions.CallFailedException">If the call fails.</exception>
    Task<Balance> GetBalanceAsync(string asset, CancellationToken ct = default);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets account balances.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ct">Cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>The account balances.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:ElonMuskBot.Core.Exceptions.CallFailedException">If the call fails.</exception>
    Task<IList<Balance>> GetBalancesAsync(CancellationToken ct = default);

    ...
}

///<inheritdoc cref="IBotClient"/>
public abstract class BotClientBase : IBotClient
{
    
}

///<inheritdoc/>
public class SpotBotClient : BotClientBase
{
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that ReSharper had it built-in.

Alt+Enter on the overriden method and then "Copy documentation from base".